# Java - Scanning Items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class which creates a 'Purchase' object. This object can be recorded to an ArrayList 'purchaseList' using the recordItem() method. However, I want to create a function that can return a specific Purchase object given an itemNo integer, I have shown my code so far in getPurchase() but am having trouble getting it working.

```
public class Purchase {

private String name;
private double price;
private int itemNo;
private int sort;
private ArrayList purchaseList = new ArrayList();

public Purchase(String name, double price, int itemNo, int sort) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.itemNo = itemNo;
    this.sort = sort;
}

public void recordItem(int itemNumber, String description, double unitPrice, int sort) {
    Purchase newPurchase = new Purchase(description, unitPrice, itemNumber, sort);
    purchaseList.add(newPurchase);
}

public int getItemNo() {
    return itemNo;
}

  public Purchase getPurchase(int itemNumber) {
    for(int i = 0; i < purchaseList.size(); i++) {
        if(purchaseList[i].getItemNo() == itemNumber) {
            return purchaseList[i];
        }
        else return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`purchaseList[i]` is valid when you work with arrays.

When working with `List` objects, to retrieve the `i`th element, you have to invoke the [`List.get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method. Like this:

```
purchaseList.get(i)
```

And so, your method has to be refactored to:

```
public Purchase getPurchase(int itemNumber) {
    for(int i = 0; i < purchaseList.size(); i++) {
        if(purchaseList.get(i).getItemNo() == itemNumber) {
            return purchaseList.get(i);
        }
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Also, in order to avoid casting from `Object` to `Purchase`, you have to make your `List` generic.

```
private List<Purchase> purchaseList = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
```

This way the compiler will ensure that the objects you add to the list are of type `Purchase` and will not force you to cast them to something specific when being got.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however when I use this I get an error with the getItemNo() method, saying that it cannot find symbol. The return also gives an error, stating that purchaseList.get(i) is an Object not a Purchase

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPurchase()` method logic is incorrect. You shouldn't exit after the first condition is not met.

Try changing it like this:

```
// Change the declaration like this
private List<Purchase> purchaseList = new ArrayList<Purchase>();

// And change the method like this:
public Purchase getPurchase(int itemNumber) {
    for(Purchase purchase : purchaseList) {
        if(purchase.getItemNo() == itemNumber) {
            return purchase;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also `recordItem()` and `getPurchase()` don't look like they belong inside the `Purchase` class.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `purchaseList[i].getItemNo()` to `purchaseList.get(i).getItemNo()`